# One model response for different models

Tags: oop, design-patterns, groovy

I am trying to cast/map an API endpoint response to APIResponse.groovy. This can simply be done if I have an APIResponse model like

**APIResponse.groovy**

```
Integer age
String gender
Integer zip
Education education
String marital_status
Boolean magazine_buyer
Boolean outdoor_and_adventure
```

I want to group them as Demographics, Household and InterestPurchase. Like..

**Demographics.groovy**

```
Integer age
String gender
Integer zip
...
```

**Household.groovy**

```
Education education
Integer household_income
...
```

**InterestPurchase.groovy**

```
Boolean magazine_buyer
Boolean outdoor_and_adventure
...
```

I thought of something like

**APIResponse.groovy**

```
inteface APIResponse implements Household, Demographics, InterestPurchase{

}
```

but of course, this would not work since members of an interface is final and static..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what approach you are using to cast/map api response to **APIResponse.groovy**. If you can provide more on this, may be I can help in a better way.

Here are some approaches you can try:

1. Map **Demographics.groovy, Household.groovy and InterestPurchase.groovy** with api response individually and then map these with APIResponse.groovy.
2. If its not required to make APIResponse.groovy interface, then you can make **Demographics.groovy, Household.groovy and InterestPurchase.groovy** abstract class.
3. If you want to go with interface approach, then don't declare the fields, just make **getter and setter methods** for these variables in their respective interface.

Comment: In the 2nd option, what to do after getting the abstract class?

Comment: Then fields in those classes won't be static and final and will be available to APIResponse. And you can directly map your response with APIResponse.

Comment: I am using com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper, I think I need to create my custom mapper that checks the super classes